# How to transfer files between not directly connected computers

Tags: linux, file-transfer

I need to transfer files between two computers, but they are not directly connected (they are in different networks).

I have used TeamViewer for this task before, but (AFAIK) in the version 13 the feature is gone for Linux platforms.

Is there any other tool to do this? (Only the file transfer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two simple options:

1. using a Cloud Storage Service (Dropbox, GDrive, OneDrive, iCloud Drive or whatever)
2. using a Peer-2-Peer VPN Software (don't have much experience with it, but beyond any board tools, https://www.freelan.org/, https://www.catapultsoft.com, https://peervpn.net might do the job)

Comment: I did not know about the VPN software (at least for p2p transfers), but I think that freelan is what I was looking for. Thanks.